# How to detect character set of a file in Angular 8?

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, character-encoding, filereader

I am wondering how to detect the character set of a file before I read it in using the FileReader Web API. I need to know what the file charset is before I read it in using `fileReader.readAsText(file, "UTF-8")` where "UTF-8" for me at the moment is unknown.

Is there any npm packages that I can use with Angular or any manual Vanilla way of detecting a character set without looking at the signatures or using a BOM code (files on my PC saved in either ISO-8859-1 or UTF-8 have same signature and no BOM code).

The packages I have tried to use so far are 'encoding', 'chardet' and 'encoding-japanese'. These don't work with Angular 8 as they are made for use with Node.

**Back story:** 
 I have a CSV and as soon as it saves in Excel, it saves with the encoding of ISO-8859-1 and I cannot expect all my clients to save their files with a specific encoding (non-technically minded folk). However, other clients may use Notepad++ which will save these files in UTF-8. I need a way of determining the encoding used to stop characters like: "�" appearing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `encoding-japanese` package in the Angular app. Try the following

1. Add the package to `package.json` and run `npm install`

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    ...,
    "encoding-japanese": "^1.0.30",
  }
}
```

2. Use the package in the app.

Controller

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';

declare const require: any;
export const Encoding = require('encoding-japanese');

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  encoding: string;

  constructor() { }

  onUpload(event: any) {
    this.detectEncoding(event.currentTarget.files[0]).subscribe(
      encoding => {
        console.log('File encoding is: ' + encoding);
        this.encoding = encoding;
      }
    );
  }

  private detectEncoding(file): Observable<string> {
    let result = new Subject<string>();

    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (e) => {
      const codes = new Uint8Array(e.target.result as ArrayBuffer);
      const detectedEncoding = Encoding.detect(codes);
      result.next(detectedEncoding);
    };
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);

    return result.asObservable();
  }
}
```

Template

```
<input type="file" (change)="onUpload($event)"/>
<ng-container *ngIf="encoding">
  <p>File encoding is: {{ encoding }}</p>
</ng-container>
```

The encoding detection mechanism was sourced from the `encoding-japanese` example [here](http://polygonplanet.github.io/encoding.js/tests/detect-file-encoding.html).

3. You could then verify the encoding inside the subscription

```js
this.detectEncoding(event.currentTarget.files[0]).subscribe(
  encoding => {
    if (encoding === 'UTF8') {
      // encoding is UTF-8
    } else {
      // encoding isn't UTF-8
    }
  }
);
```

4. You could check for the following encoding strings.

   - UTF32
   - UTF16
   - UTF16BE
   - UTF16LE
   - BINARY
   - ASCII
   - JIS
   - UTF8
   - EUCJP
   - SJIS
   - UNICODE

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vjmyoh)

Comment: Just tried and it detects the file encoding successfully! I wasn't 'requiring' the package the same way as shown here and so I faced many errors. Thanks a bunch!!

Answer (score 2):

Unless your input files are really really small, I think you should check out [detect-file-encoding-and-language](https://www.npmjs.com/package/detect-file-encoding-and-language)!

I'm using it in my React application to detect the charset of subtitle files before loading them via the FileReader Web API.

This is how I do it:

```js
import languageEncoding from "detect-file-encoding-and-language";

function inputHandler(e) {
  const file = e.target.files[0];
  languageEncoding(file).then(fileInfo => console.log(fileInfo.encoding));  // UTF-8
}
```

And of course, you'll have to install it:

```sh
$ npm i detect-file-encoding-and-language
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use [detect-character-encoding](https://www.npmjs.com/package/detect-character-encoding) which is an external npm module which will do the job for you like this.

> ```js
> const fs = require('fs');
> const detectCharacterEncoding = require('detect-character-encoding');
>
> const fileBuffer = fs.readFileSync('file.txt');
> const charsetMatch = detectCharacterEncoding(fileBuffer);
>
> console.log(charsetMatch);
> // {
> //   encoding: 'UTF-8',
> //   confidence: 60
> // }
> ```

Comment: Hello thanks for replying, I keep getting told that this 'fs' module is something that doesn't work in browsers with Angular. Nonetheless,  'detect-character-encoding' is a package I have not tried and shall reply back and give answer if this works.

Comment: Yes they are right about it. `fs` will not work in your browser but if you're using `angular-universal` or `ssr` then you will be using a `server.ts`. You can use `fs` in that file but it totally depends on what you're looking for.

Comment: Yeah I'm not using either of those. The CSV's contents is read  in the client via FileReader API and then contents is sent for processing in a .NET Core API. Thing is, by the time it is sent to API, it has already read it wrongly and the UNICODE replacement characters are in the file contents.

Comment: Oh you have a backend. If you have a backend then I think it'll be done from backend only because all the `fs` related tasks are done from backend.